# Summing up Daily credit expenses in SQL

Tags: sql, sum, sql-server-2014

I have a table like this - it is a credit card transactions table of specific customer: 
(As you know when using the credit card for jan the actual payment that is charged from the bank account for this customer on February,
mostly on 2019-02-15 but there is one transaction that is going to be charged on 2019-02-10.

```
   Customer   orig_date   Payment charge_date
    100400    2019-01-01   500    2019-02-15
    100400    2019-01-01   100    2019-02-10
    100400    2019-01-01   400    2019-02-15
    100400    2019-01-04   300    2019-02-15
    100400    2019-01-09   100    2019-02-15
    100400    2019-01-10   50     2019-02-15
    100400    2019-02-09   1700   2019-03-15
    100400    2019-02-13   800    2019-03-15 
    100400    2019-02-16   500    2019-03-15
```

And My Desired output should be like this, on each day I want to see in a field near it the nearest expected charge Amount and the date the charge is going to happen.

```
Customer  Tr_Date ChargeDate  Expected_Charge_Amt
100400  2019-01-01 2019-02-15    500 
100400  2019-01-01 2019-02-10    100     
100400  2019-01-02 2019-02-15    900     
100400  2019-01-02 2019-02-10    100  
100400  2019-01-03 2019-02-15    900  
100400  2019-01-03 2019-02-10    100    
100400  2019-01-04 2019-02-15    1200
100400  2019-01-04 2019-02-10    100   
100400  2019-01-05 2019-02-15    1200    
100400  2019-01-05 2019-02-10    100  
100400  2019-01-06 2019-02-15    1200 
100400  2019-01-06 2019-02-10    100       
100400  2019-01-07 2019-02-15    1200    
100400  2019-01-07 2019-02-10    100
100400  2019-01-08 2019-02-15    1200 
100400  2019-01-08 2019-02-10    100 
100400  2019-01-09 2019-02-15    1300   
100400  2019-01-09 2019-02-10    100 
100400  2019-01-10 2019-02-15    1350
100400  2019-01-10 2019-02-10    100
```

... {All Dates Between with no change}

```
100400  2019-01-31 2019-02-15    1350
100400  2019-01-31 2019-02-10    100
```

...{All Dates Between with no change}

```
100400  2019-02-09 2019-02-15    1350
100400  2019-02-09 2019-02-10    100
100400  2019-02-09 2019-03-15    1700

100400  2019-02-10 2019-02-15    1350
100400  2019-02-10 2019-03-15    1700
```

...{All Dates Between with no change}

```
100400  2019-02-14 2019-02-15    1350
100400  2019-02-14 2019-03-15    2500
```

..{All Dates Between with no change}

```
100400  2019-02-15 2019-03-15    3000
100400  2019-02-16 2019-03-15    3000
```

I Hope You've got the point of algoritem. 
  I'm really having an hard time writing a query for this.Could you 
  help me?

Answer (score 0):

Its somewhat unclear what you want to achieve. Do you want to sum up the expected charges by customer, month of `orig_date` and date of `charge_date`?

If so, something like this should work:

`SELECT 
customer, 
cast(orig_date as DATE) as orig_month, 
charge_date, 
sum(payment) as Expected_Charge_amt 
from table_name 
group by customer, cast(orig_date as DATE), charge_date`

Comment: No. It's simple for me. I want to add for each day the cumlative sum of the cc expences. I wrote an example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all pending transactions.

To do this, start with a list of dates.  Then a `cross apply` or `join`:

```
with dates as 
      select convert(date, '2019-01-01') as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < '2019-02-28'
     )
select t.customer, d.dte as tr_date, t.charge_date,
       t.payment as expected_chart_amount
from dates d join
     transactions t
     on d.dte >= t.orig_date and
        d.dte <= t.charge_date
where t.customer = 100400
order by d.dte, t.charge_date;
```